# Infinite sum conundrum: $S_1 = 1 + 2 + \ldots$, $S_2 = \frac{1}{2} + 1 + 2 + \ldots$, $S_1-S_2$ finite or infinite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

$$S_1 = 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots$$

$$S_2 = \frac{1}{2} + 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots$$

Now case 1:

$$\left.\Delta S = S_1 - S_2 = \frac{1}{2}\,\right\}\text{finite value}$$

Case 2:

$$\Delta S = S_1 - S_2 = \frac{1}{2} + \underbrace{(1 + 1 + 1 + \ldots)}_{\infty\text{ value!}}$$

In one case, I see a finite  difference whereas in the other, an infinite. So, which one is right and why?

Comment: You should note that $\infty-\infty$ is not well defined.

Comment: You can only subtract *convergent* sequences from one another.

Comment: See rule 3)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Properties_of_summation_methods

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*If* $\lim_{n \to \infty}u_n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}v_n$ *exist* and are *finite* then

> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty}(v_n-u_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}v_n-\lim_{n \to \infty}u_n. \tag1
> $$

You seem to have applied $(1)$ to
$$
u_n=1+2+\cdots+n, \quad v_n=\frac12+1+2+\cdots+n
$$ which is *not justified* since
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}u_n=\infty,\qquad \lim_{n \to \infty}v_n=\infty.
$$

Comment: Can you suggest me some book from which I can systematically study infinite series?

Comment: @user115962 Sure. Have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494518/book-on-infinite-series   and here  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482365/what-is-a-great-book-to-read-about-sequences-sums-and-products

Comment: And may I just add, strongly resist the temptation to click on any Numberphile YouTube videos until you have got a good foundation from those references.

Comment: @Deepak There are some decent ones (but yeah, that Numberphile -_-)