# Finding formulas for sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was searching for ways and techniques of writing formulas for non arithmetic and non geometric sequences such as the sequence below:

> 1 , 3 , 6 , 10 , 15 , ...

I found this  [webpage](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~bkell/21110-2010s/formula.html).

My question is concerning this [problem](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~bkell/21110-2010s/formula.html#quadratic). The author stated that:

> Since we had to take differences twice before we found a constant row, we guess that the formula for the sequence is a polynomial of degree 2, i.e., a quadratic polynomial. (In general, if you have to take differences m times to get a constant row, the formula is probably a polynomial of degree m.)

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Examples:*

Consider an AP, where the $n$-the term is $a+(n-1)d$, which is a polynomial of degree $1$ in $n$. Take difference **once**, and you get a series of constants, i.e. $d$, the common difference.

For the same AP, the sum to the $n$-th term is $\frac n2 (2a+(n-1)d)=(a-\tfrac d2)\ n+d\cdot n^2$, which is a polynomial of degree $2$ (quadratic) in $n$. Take the difference once to get the $n$-th term of the AP, and again to get a series of constants, i.e. $d$.

This is in a way similar to differentiation in calculus. If you have to differentiate a polynomial $m$ times in order to get a constant, then the original polynomial must be of degree $m$.

---

*More formal answer*:

Conder a quadratic sequence, where the $n$-th term is given by:
$$T_n=an^2+bn+c$$

Taking difference once, and again:

$$\begin{align}
\Delta T_n&=T_n-T_{n-1}\\
&=\left[an^2+bn+c\right]-\left[a(n-1)^2+b(n-1)+c\right]\\
&=a(2n-1)+b\\
&=2an+(b-a)\\
\Delta^2 T_n&=\Delta T_n-\Delta T_{n-1}\\
&=2a(n-(n-1))\\
&=2a\quad \text{(constant)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: My question is about why should it be a quadratic if I took the difference twice

Comment: See expanded solution above.

Comment: Thanks, I would be grateful if you provided me with resources on how to write formulas for exponential sequences.

Comment: You're welcome. What do you mean by exponential sequences?

Comment: I mean sequences that are not written as polynomial functions , but rather as exponential or other functions.

Comment: This might be helpful. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482365/what-is-a-great-book-to-read-about-sequences-sums-and-products

Comment: Thank you again.